# Alternative for SELECT INTO IN for MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I´m looking for an alternative for

SQL

```
SELECT * INTO othertable IN “new.mdb” FROM onetable;
```

I can do it with

```
SELECT * INTO  othertable FROM onetable;
```

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE othertable SELECT * FROM onetable;
```

**But I can´t do it copying the table into another database.**

Anyone knows how? **I´m trying to do something like CREATE TABLE…**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `create table newdb.othertable as select . . .`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Thanks a lot! :D